# How to fix CORS error for passport- twitter login using Express.js and Angular?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, twitter-oauth

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'about:blank' (redirected from 'http://localhost:7777/auth/twitter') from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Server.js

```
...

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8888');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    next();
});
...
```

passportConfig.js

```
// auth with twitter
router.get('/twitter', passport.authenticate('twitter'));

// redirect to home page after successfully login via twitter
router.get('/twitter/redirect', passport.authenticate('twitter', {
    successRedirect: config.clientHomePageURL,
    failureRedirect: '/auth/login/failed',
}));
```

Comment: Do you use `cors` module?

Comment: Yes, I tried the CORS module also. 

app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:8888', // allow to server to accept request from different origin
  methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
  credentials: true, // allow session cookie from browser to pass through
 }));
@ÖmürcanCengiz

Comment: Try use express cors middleware

Comment: I tried cors middleware also. But I am getting the same error. -@ÖmürcanCengiz